# How to get Notification when region Changes of the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geofencing, region-monitoring

I am working on application in which I have to use region monitoring.
When the location of user changes according to that the user will get notification about the location that user now is in the new location, Even when the application is in background.
I am trying from the last few days and searched in the Google but I am not finding the solution or any idea that how to do. 
 Is here anyone who can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **geofencing** with the help of `CLLocationManager` and call the `startMonitoringForRegion`

Make a function like this and start monitoring for region

```
-(void)notificationForRegion:(CLLocationDegrees) latitude withLongitude:(CLLocationDegrees) longitude andIdentifier : (NSString*) identifer {
    CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    CLCircularRegion * regionForMonitoring = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) radius:50.0 identifier:identifer];
    regionForMonitoring.notifyOnExit = TRUE;
    [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:regionForMonitoring];
}
```

Implement `didEnterRegion` delegate method of  `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in `AppDelegate` as `AppDelegate` object remains in memory always and schedule your local notifications here.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    UILocalNotification * localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"You are now in the region";
    localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [manager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];  
}
```

Call the above `notificationForRegion` function as follows

After getting your `location`

```
[self notificationForRegion:location.coordinate.latitude withLongitude:location.coordinate.longitude andIdentifier:@"your identifier"];
```

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) What i have to write in place of latitude and longitude, current location latitude and longitude?

Comment: you just pass your location by calling this function `notificationForRegion`